# R-Shiny-Query DataFrame by string

Tags: r, string, dataframe, shiny, querying

I have a dataframe df with the column names a,b and c.

Furthermore, i have a string s in the format "a<3".

How can I query df for s ?

df[s] does not work, as R sees s as a column name.

Thank you for your answers in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should create better example data... Have a look at this example code with solution:

```
a <- c(1:3)
b <- c("a<3","a<2","a<1")
data <- data.frame(a,b) # Example data frame

data_filtered <- data[data$b == "a<3", ] # Here i filter the column b directly for the string "a<3"

#or

s <- c("a<3")

data_filtered2 <- data[data$b %in% s, ] # Here i filter the column b for the string "a<3" in s
```